# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ifaddrs.h': No such file or directory

Tags: vcpkg

I use vcpkg to install live555

but build failed

here is information:

```
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:146 (message):

Command failed: C:/Users/yujie/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.19.2-windows/cmake-3.19.2-win32-x86/bin/cmake.exe --build . --config Debug --target install -- -v -j5

Working Directory: C:/Users/yujie/vcpkg/buildtrees/live555/x86-windows-dbg

See logs for more information:
  C:\Users\yujie\vcpkg\buildtrees\live555\install-x86-windows-dbg-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
scripts/cmake/vcpkg_build_cmake.cmake:105 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
scripts/cmake/vcpkg_install_cmake.cmake:45 (vcpkg_build_cmake)
ports/live555/portfile.cmake:30 (vcpkg_install_cmake)
scripts/ports.cmake:142 (include)
```

and i open "install-x86-windows-dbg-out.log"

here is end of log:

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/groupsock.dir/groupsock/GroupsockHelper.cpp.obj 
H:\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\Hostx64\x86\cl.exe   /TP  - 
IC:\Users\yujie\vcpkg\buildtrees\live555\src\555-latest-0360bd0751.clean\BasicUsageEnvironment\include -IC:\Users\yujie\vcpkg\buildtrees\live555\src\555-latest-0360bd0751.clean\groupsock\include -IC:\Users\yujie\vcpkg\buildtrees\live555\src\555-latest-0360bd0751.clean\liveMedia\include -IC:\Users\yujie\vcpkg\buildtrees\live555\src\555-latest-0360bd0751.clean\UsageEnvironment\include /nologo /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /utf-8 /GR /EHsc /MP  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Z7 /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\groupsock.dir\groupsock\GroupsockHelper.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\groupsock.dir\groupsock.pdb /FS -c C:\Users\yujie\vcpkg\buildtrees\live555\src\555-latest-0360bd0751.clean\groupsock\GroupsockHelper.cpp
 C:\Users\yujie\vcpkg\buildtrees\live555\src\555-latest-0360bd0751.clean\groupsock\GroupsockHelper.cpp(46): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ifaddrs.h': No such file or directory
 ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the best solution, but here I how I managed to get live555 built & installed with vcpkg for x64-windows and x64-windows-static.

Edit *...\vcpkg\ports\live555\CMakeLists.txt*, define **NO_GETIFADDRS**. *ifaddrs.h* is not available on Windows, unless some custom port of that header is installed.

I added this block to the live555 CMakeLists.txt

```
if (WIN32)
 add_definitions(-DNO_GETIFADDRS)
endif(WIN32)
```

Comment: There's a Github issue that is tracking this problem (and referencing this SO question):
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/17165